# Selenium not able to locate the element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape data from https://in.puma.com/in/en/mens/mens-new-arrivals . The complete data is loaded when the show all button is clicked.

I used selenium to generate the click and load the rest of the page, however - I'm getting an error

```
"TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: "
```

See my code below.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from lxml import etree as et

chrome_driver_path = "driver/chromedriver"

url = 'https://in.puma.com/in/en/mens/mens-new-arrivals'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser.get(url)

x_path_to_load_more = '//*[@data-component-id="a_tspn9cqoeth"]'
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
button_locate = wait(browser,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,x_path_to_load_more)))
button_locate.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

`@data-component-id` seem to be dynamic. It means that the value will be different (not `"a_tspn9cqoeth"`) each time you open that page. Try to search by another attribiute value:

```
x_path_to_load_more = '//div[@class="text-center"]/button[contains(@class, "show-more-button")]'
```

or

```
x_path_to_load_all = '//div[@class="text-center"]/button[contains(@class, "show-all-button")]'
```

Also it's better to use `EC.element_to_be_clickable` instead of `EC.presence_of_element_located`

**UPDATE**

Since click on button might be intercepted by Cookies footer try to scroll page down before making click:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver.find_element('xpath', '//body').send_keys(Keys.END)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, however when the code is run, I got an error "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted:  is not clickable at point (694, 601). Another element would receive the click". . When the browser is loaded, it asks for location permission, and maybe the error is because of that.

Comment: @sebastian I see Puma.com Cookies footer at the bottom of screen so you need either accept cookies by clicking "Accept" button or hide footer using JavScript or scroll the page so that LoadMore/ShowAll button will be visible

Answer (score 0):

The xpath is not correct, try

```
x_path_to_load_more = "//button[contains(., 'Show All')]"
```

To verify the effectiveness of the xpath inspect the page, open the find bar with Command + F or Control + F and paste your xpath

Comment: Got the correct locator using.                                                'x_path_to_load_more ="//button[contains(., 'Show All')]"'

Comment: however when the code is run, got an error "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted:  is not clickable at point (694, 601). Another element would receive the click". . When the browser is loaded, it asks for location permission, and maybe the error is because of that.

Comment: it happens because the click is intercepted by another element in the page. You can use Javascript to click on the element with 'browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button_locate)' and it should work

Comment: Thanks a ton and it does load the page, the page is being loaded as I scroll down - should I run the 'browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
' after click to get all the elements? Or is just click enough? I want to mark your answer accepted unfortunately I have less than 15 reputation points.

Comment: you should first click and then scroll at the bottom of the page so you will see all the elements you need for your task